# SONAR analysis against multi module projects

Tags: maven, sonarqube, multi-module

I have a question regarding sonar analysis with maven.

I have a group of projects built by maven, and a handy pom files to aggregate the projects together, so that I can run one maven build for all projects.

I also would like to run sonar analysis against the aggregated pom. The analysis is done without errors, the only problem is the aggregated result: even though I run the analysis against the aggregated pom, I would like to get individual analysis result for each projects instead an aggregated report. Is there any configuration/argument to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK, we can drill-down to each module by using the sonar project dashboard. It's just clicking at the `Components menu` at the left hand side menu.

Comment: Hi Charlee, Thanks for quick response. I checked my sonar and found out my projects can be seen as "sub project" now. Question is the alerts in quality profiles I set for projects do not apply to sub projects, and there is no warnings available for sub project dashboard. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to add `some wigets` to the `sub project dashboard`? e.g. `Rules Compliance`, `Useless Code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can be achieved the way you're doing it. And you would advise you not to continue in this direction, as creating an "aggregator POM" is a just a workaround which has many side effects in Sonar.

The correct way to achieve what you want is to analyse each project independently and to create views & sub-views to aggregate all the information the way you want. For this, you need the [Views Plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/).

Comment: Hi Fabrice, actually I do not want the aggregated view. I use aggregated pom only for simplifying build infrastructure. I have dozens of projects in Jenkins, and do not want to maintain the sonar build step for each of them as running SONAR analysis for every build is time consuming. So I use aggregated pom to run SONAR periodically, and add new project to the pom if necessary, otherwise I have to create another dozens of jenkins jobs only for SONAR analysis, and everytime when I add new project, I have to create a SONAR job as well...

Comment: Well, I understand your point, but you have no choice if you want to make things clean.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam This "Views Plugin" you mention seems not to be free. One has to pay for it, right?

Comment: @Enrique Indeed, you're right. This is the business model that allows SonarSource to provide a big part of its product for free: you have to buy some extensions if you want to have advanced features.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Sounds fair to me. It's up to the company I work for to invest in good tools. Thanks for the info.